# How to connect 2 ASP.NET MVC 3 Site into one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently writing an ASP.NET MVC3 website. I am new to ASP.NET MVC3. In my site I have a page which says click here for a sample asp.net mvc website (This is a new sample which is another asp.net MVC site - The demo displays a customer login, place an order and check out and check order details. - This is yet to be completed)

when I complete this project. I want to purchase a domain name and host it.I dont want to host 2 different asp.net mvc3 How can I use a single domain name and have both my asp.net mvc project. Also I only have one SQL Server database.

For example : say the domain name is - www.kalls23.com (this is a mvc 3 project) and I want sample like www.kalls23.com/sample/MvcSite - Which takes the user to (sample mvc3 project)

How can I structure the solution on VS2010? Any other ideas and recommendations?

Comment: I feel like that would be a deployment issue more than how to structure it in Visual Studio.  You could probably just deploy your sample project into a subdomain like `sample.kalls23.com` and let IIS take care of serving the right site for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into Areas especially if you have one database. This would make your application one project and a lot can be shared. A bit depends on how much sharing of UI is desired.

If UI is completely different and it is mostly a sharing of database structures (assuming EF code first for example) and maybe repositories, then I would recommend one solution with multiple ASP.NET MVC3 sites, a model/repository/services project (maybe more split out if complex), and a test project if tests are desired or planned.

I would probably opt for my first recommendation if this is not a terribly complex project as it will make your life easier and builds faster.

Good Luck! If you have more specifics you might get better recommendations still (testing plans, complexity, UI sharing, database entity overlap, etc)